# Scroll event isn't propagated to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a grid-div with `overflow-y: scroll;` and this grid-div is some time 10000pixels long. On mouserhover of a specific items of a grid-div I am firing mouserhover event, and user shows tooltip over the element. Now user add this popup under the body element. and user has written scroll event on window that if scroll event is fired, hide the tooltip. but when user is still over my grid-div, scroll event is fired only on grid-div, and event is not propagate to any parent elements(html,body,window) so user can't hide that element.

So here why scroll event is not propagated like click events? what is the possible solution to propagate the event?

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrnanpmL/1/) of what issue I am facing, Here I haven't added tooltip but only sample code to reproduce that scrolling issue. Here I am expecting that for every "Scrolled On div" there should be "Scrolled On Window" written in log.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  // While scrolling on div why this event is not fired?
  $('#eventData').append('<div>Scrolled On Window</div>');
});

$('#grid-div').on("scroll", function() {
  $('#eventData').append('<div>Scrolled On div</div>');
});
```

```css
#grid-div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-div">
  <br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A
</div>
<div id="eventData">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the code you are having a problem with. By your rep count you should know this. Also scroll events do not bubble when [triggered by elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: Added fiddle...

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Yahh I was creating a fiddle... but posted question early by mistake ;)

Comment: @Pete: Updated fiddle

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want?! Which one is the tooltip!

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy:  Here I haven't added tooltip but only sample code to reproduce that scrolling issue. Here I am expecting that for every "Scrolled On div" there should be "Scrolled On Window" written in log.

Comment: You probably need to [debounce or throtle](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/) the scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll events do not bubble up when it is an element that is triggering the event

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll
>
> Bubbles: Not on elements, but bubbles to the default view when fired
>   on the document

If you want to also have the window scroll event to execute you will need to trigger it yourself

```
$(window).trigger("scroll");
```

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(e,e2) {
  // While scrolling on div why this event is not fired?
  //get original event if triggered programmatically
  e = e2 || e;
  $('#eventData').append('<div>Scrolled On Window</div>');
});

$('#grid-div').on("scroll", function(e) {
  $('#eventData').append('<div>Scrolled On div</div>');
  //all parameters after the first will be passed to the event callback
  //so here passing it the original event.
  $(window).trigger("scroll",e);
});
```

```css
#grid-div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-div">
  <br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A
</div>
<div id="eventData">
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm, is there any approach where I can ignore writing $(window).trigger("scroll",e);???

Comment: If your goal is to hide the tooltip why not just hide it in the grid-div scroll event?

Comment: grid div is independent component, and tooltip is independent component, so I don't want tooltip specific code in grid component

Comment: @ParagBhayani, If they are independent of each other then neither should try to interact with each other or to solve a problem that involves the other. That would be the end-developer's problem.

Comment: hmmm, that is why I was wondering why scroll isn't propagated, cause it should be generic approch...

Answer (score 2):

There is known approach like firing the event manually as suggested by others

```
$(window).trigger("scroll");
```

And then there is another generic approach for this, is to listen scroll event on capturing phase(older IE browsers doesn't support this).

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  console.log("document Scrolled during capture phase")
}, true);
```